# How can I access what the user passes in the command to use it the command error handler? discord.py

Tags: error-handling, discord, discord.py

How can I access what the user passes in the command `user` so I can use it the `user.error` handler?
here's what I've tried and didn't work:

```
    @commands.command(aliases= ["info"])
    async def user(self, ctx, *, member: discord.Member=None):
        colors = [0xad1457, 0xe67e22, 0x992d22, 0x607d8b, 0x7289da, 0x71368a, 0x11806a]
        if member == None:
            embed = discord.Embed(color = random.choice(colors))
            embed.add_field(name = "**Joined Discord**:", value = "`" + ctx.author.created_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %I:%M") + "`")
            embed.add_field(name = "**Joined Server:**", value = "`" + ctx.author.joined_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %I:%M") + "`")

            embed.set_footer(text = f"{ctx.author.name}")
            embed.set_image(url = f"{ctx.author.avatar_url}")
            await ctx.send(embed = embed)
        else:
            embed = discord.Embed(color = random.choice(colors))
            embed.add_field(name = "**Joined Discord**:", value = "`" + member.created_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %I:%M") + "`")
            embed.add_field(name = "**Joined Server:**", value = "`" + member.joined_at.strftime("%d/%m/%Y %I:%M") + "`")

            embed.set_footer(text = f"{member.name}")
            embed.set_image(url = f"{member.avatar_url}")
            await ctx.send(embed = embed)
            
    @user.error
    async def user_error(self, ctx, error):
        if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
            await ctx.send(f"**Wrong format. Use {ctx.prefix}user <user>**")
        elif isinstance(error, commands.MemberNotFound):
            await ctx.send(f"**  - {ctx.author.name}**, I can't find {member.id} in the server.")
        else:
            raise error
```

so I want to access what the user passes in the command so I can use it in the command handler.

**and another question, how can I make the `aliases` doesn't need the prefix to run the command
example: in my code above I have `info` as aliases, I want if the user typed info(without the prefix) the bot will answer.**

Answer (score 0):

You can get the passed arguments and keyword arguments with `ctx.args` and `ctx.kwargs`.

EDIT:

```
@user.error
async def user_error(self, ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingRequiredArgument):
        await ctx.send(f"**Wrong format. Use {ctx.prefix}user <user>**")
    elif isinstance(error, commands.MemberNotFound):
        await ctx.send(f"**  - {ctx.author.name}**, I can't find a member with {error.argument} in the server.")
    else:
        raise error
```

Comment: and where do i put that?